# How to resolve "Illegal cyclic inheritance" compilation error when using a Java enum in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums

It looks like the Scala compiler can't handle enums that implement an interface with a static method that captures the enum type as a method parameter.

Consider the following interface:

```
//Identifiable.java
package com.example;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public interface Identifiable {
    String name();

    static <E extends Enum<E> & Identifiable> Map<String, E> valuesByName(final E[] values) {
        return Stream.of(values).collect(toMap(Identifiable::name, Function.identity()));
    }
}
```

---

And an enum that implements it:

```
//Size.java
package com.example;

public enum Size implements Identifiable {
    SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE;
}
```

---

Finally, a Scala app that uses the Size enum:

```
//Broken.scala
package com.example

object Broken extends App {
  println(Size.SMALL)
}
```

The following compilation error occurs when attempting to build the classes (in 2.12.3):

> Error:(4, 10) illegal cyclic inheritance involving class Size
>   println(Size.SMALL)

Am I missing something or is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: I put the three source files in an empty directory, started `sbt`, and typed `++2.12.3` and then `run`, and it compiled fine and ran and printed `SMALL`.

Comment: @SethTisue, I can confirm that I see the same error using Scala 2.12.4. The error seems to go if I remove `valuesByName` from the `Identifiable` but I have no idea why.

Comment: @SethTisue i just tried compiling and running the same code from command line using SBT 1.0.3 and Scala 2.12.3 which resulted in the same error 
`/blah/blah/blah/com/example/Broken.scala:4:10: illegal cyclic inheritance involving class Size`

Comment: Here's a full transcript of my successful run. What am I doing differently? https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/d91427937cac4faa8bf9f2b9e68d8a82

Comment: @SethTisue i'm actually seeing inconsistencies. compilation fails on the first attempt, but succeeds on the second and all subsequent attempts. however, if i change the source of `Broken.scala` to force SBT to recompile it, the build fails again. basically if SBT attempts to compile the Scala file by itself - `Compiling 1 Scala source to` - (because the Java files are already compiled), it fails. but if it builds all three from scratch - `Compiling 1 Scala source and 2 Java sources to` - it succeeds...

Comment: @SethTisue seems like forcing the build order to `JavaThenScala` produces consistent compilation failures: `compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala`

Comment: Aha — yes, seems like a bug to me. I'd suggest searching https://github.com/scala/bug to see if it's been reported before or not

Comment: @SethTisue it didn't look like there were any existing issues for this scenario, so i opened a new one: [10639](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10639)

Comment: fixed in 2.12.9